# Set up a remote machine as a proxy server

Tags: proxy, webserver

I apologise if this is very basic, I am a beginner to computer science and am still learning.

I am running OS X Sierra on a MacBook Air (Client) and I have a heavy machine running Ubuntu 14.04 (Server). These 2 machines are connected via a high speed local network.

The problem I have is this: Server has access to high speed ethernet, while the internet available to Client is very slow. Is it possible to use Server as a proxy server through which Client can connect to the internet? Since Client and Server are connected via a high speed local connection, that shouldn't be a bottleneck, and I should be able to achieve high speed (similar to Server's) on Client.

How do I use Server (the remote machine) as a proxy server?

Comment: Have you done any research on the production you want to setup a proxy on to use to see how that is typically configured to at least try something or mention that I read this or that and tried this or that with no success and so forth?

Comment: I read various things - such as Squid, PHProxy, etc. But I am unable to make sense of much of it as I am not familiar with even the basics of how a network works